# Convert from object to array

Tags: laravel

So I am getting result like this:

```
[{"modelone_year":2021,"modeltwo_year":2019}]
```

How do I need to convert this to this?

```
[2021,2019]
```

This is from where I get result:

```
 $years = Invoice::query()
          ->join('expenses', 'expenses.company_id','=', 'invoices.company_id')
          ->groupBy('modelone_year')
          ->groupBy('modeltwo_year')
          ->get();
```

Comment: you will convert in javascript or with php

Comment: yeah with php here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a collection and have to convert to an array. then you can use `array_value` (https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-values.php). You will receive all values as an array:
Like that:

```php
<?php
$collection = '[{"modelone_year":2021,"modeltwo_year":2019}]';
$arr = $collection->toArray();

$val = array_values($arr[0]);

print_r($val);
// output [2021,2019]
```

Comment: ```Expected parameter of type 'string', 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection' provided``` for ```json_decode```

Comment: ok :-) Then you change only one line. instead json_decode use `$arr = $collection->toArray();`. I updated my answer!